# No Scrollbar - JScrollPane with JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jsplitpane

I have a JSplitPane with

```
JSplitPane jSplitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, movieSearchResultTableScrollPane, movieSearchInfoScrollPane);
```

I have set:

```
jSplitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
```

The `movieSearchResultTableScrollPane` has a JTable and if drag the splitpane to the left, a horizontal scrollbar is going to visible after some length.

The `movieSearchInfoScrollPane` has a JPanel `movieSearchInfoPanel` attached as:

```
movieSearchInfoScrollPane.setViewportView(movieSearchInfoPanel);
```

`movieSearchInfoPanel` has some label components. And I didn't specify any kind of size to the `movieSearchInfoPanel`. But If I drag the splitpane to the right I am not getting horizontal scrollbar `movieSearchInfoScrollPane`.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call setPreferredSize() for the movieSearchInfoPanel.

But it's better to use LayoutManager set for the panel. Then all the children componnets' pref sizes are used to calculate pref size of container and scroll appear automatically.